# Contour Plugin generated contours do not have enough nodes

Tags: interpolation, contour, nodes

I am using the contour plugin to generate intermediate contours.  I have a vector file with 5 foot contours and want to interpolate 1 foot contours from it.  The procedure I used was:

1. Extract nodes from my 5 foot contours vector file.
   [image: Original 5 ft contours]

[image: Nodes-from-original-5-ft-contours]

2. Create intermediate contours from nodes extracted from original 5 foot contours.
   [image: Intermediate-contours-from-Contours-plugin]
3. Nodes from intermediate contours.
   [image: Nodes-of-intermediate-contours-from-Contours-plugin]

The problem is that the intermediate contours are not very good in some of the open areas. I assume that this is due to the nodes of the intermediate contours the open areas are too far apart.

Is there a way to get the contour plugin to generate more nodes in these open areas to make the generated intermediate contours in these open areas better?